# @fullcalendar/resource-timeline@4.3.0 in react

Tags: reactjs, fullcalendar, resources, timeline

> > my code

`

```
       <FullCalendar
        defaultView="resourceTimelineDay"
        plugins={[timelinePlugin]}
        schedulerLicenseKey={my key}
        resourceColumns={[
          {
            labelText: 'Room',
            field: 'title',
          },
          {
            labelText: 'Occupancy',
            field: 'occupancy',
          },
        ]}
        resources={[
          { id: 'a', title: 'Auditorium A', occupancy: 40 },
          { id: 'b', title: 'Auditorium B', occupancy: 60 },
          { id: 'c', title: 'Auditorium C', occupancy: 40 },
          ...
        ]}
      />
```

[image: 1]

what is this gray section???

it looks like empty section
please help me

i want to remove gray section
it makes me crazy

Comment: Please post a comment !!!!!

Comment: Can't reproduce this using vanillaJS (I'm not a react user) - https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/wvEYGeb . Please provide a [mre] of the issue e.g. using codesandbox or similar, so we can investigate the issue. possibly it's something related to extra CSS in your page or something...it's certainly not part of fullCalendar itself from what I can see. See also [ask]. You can [edit] your post. Thanks

Comment: P.S. As you're new please also take the [tour], to understand how to get the best out of Stackoverflow.